# How to subscribe the AWS AMI from AWS Marketplace. Is there any API client for that, would like to write in Python3

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-marketplace

I am trying to subscribe **AWS** image from there Marketplace. I am using the **python** technology to achieve this. In EC2 client **describe_image()** method is available by using this I am able to fetch all the images available in the particular **region**. Now can you please help me out to subscribe the **ami** images from **aws Marketplace** using python script.

Comment: Is there any api client to subscribe an aws ami ?